# How to return three columns in sql query using inner join and order by?

Tags: sql-server, mysql

I am trying to write this query below, somehow my output is incorrect according the image. The query is as below and expected output is attached here as snipping for clarity regarding my issue.

```
// sql query

SELECT m.GroupID, c.CompanyName, Count(*) as Count
from maintable_YUBF3 m 
 INNER JOIN cb_vendorinformation c on m.GroupID = c.GroupID
 GROUP BY m.GroupID, c.CompanyName


     Order by Count,m.GroupID desc;
```

// this query prints this image as being incorrect
[image]

// the output of the query should be this image below
[image]

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table.

Comment: @Rick do you mind giving me an example, im searching now on google for this statement in sql

Comment: @Rick i have tried to use show create table but create is not allowed for this query

Comment: Huh?  A "database", not a "query", contains the "table".  Please show me the error message (or whatever) when you tried to do the `SHOW`.

Comment: "sql-server" and "mysql" are _different_ products; please pick the right tag.

Comment: @Rick James its sql

Comment: SQL is a generic language and standard, not a database system which has different implementations of the SQL language depending on which one you're using. Which database system are you using? (If `TOP` is a keyword in the language you're using then it's likely Microsoft SQL Server, if `LIMIT` is a keyword in it instead, then it's not SQL Server.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `GroupID` is treated as a string, then you will get what is in the dark image ("5" > "27").  If it is treated as numeric, then you will get what you see in the light-background image (5 < 27).

Providing the table schema *may* illuminate the problem.  Providing *which* product generated the output *may* illuminate the problem.